# Efficient gather (of whole rows) from a large matrix

Tags: c, performance, caching, linear-algebra, avx2

I am trying to perform a simple operation. I have a matrix that is A x B by size. I have a list of indices of length C, and I want to make a C x B matrix by collecting rows from the first matrix according to the indices. i.e. index i tells me which row from the first matrix I put into row i in the second matrix.

I presorted the indices so the algorithm is input stationary: I load in the row from the A x B matrix and write that row to all the rows in the C x B matrix.

The code looks something like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i < A; i ++)
{
    for(int k = offsets[i]; k < offsets[i+1]; k ++)
    {
           int dest = index1[k];
                
           for(int j = 0;j < C/ 8; j++)
           {
                __m256 a = _mm256_load_ps(&input[i * C + j * 8]);
                _mm256_store_ps(&output[dest * C + j * 8] ,a);
           }
     }
 }
```

The code is entirely bottlenecked by write to memory.
**This code is efficient when C is small. However it scales very poorly when C increases, which I surmise is due to cache behavior. (It takes 10x time when C = 1024 compared to C = 256).**

I tried blocking in the C dimension:

```
for(int c = 0; c < C; c+= K){
for(int i = 0;i < A; i ++)
{
    for(int k = offsets[i]; k < offsets[i+1]; k ++)
    {
           int dest = index1[k];
                
           for(int j = 0;j < C/ 8 / K; j++)
           {
                __m256 a = _mm256_load_ps(&input[i * C + c + j * 8]);
                _mm256_store_ps(&output[dest * C + c + j * 8] ,a);
           }
     }
 }
}
```

This actually slows down the code more.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you touch every value exactly once, blocking can't help you against a memory bottleneck. It could help, e.g. if you pipeline the extraction with a more expensive operation, such as a matrix-matrix product.

Comment: I don't understand why the memory bottleneck is aggravated when the C dimension increases. unfortunately I have nothing to pipeline the memory write with.

Comment: Note that memory is often not saturated with only one core on many machines (parallelism mat vélo a bit here (besides streaming store as said later)

Comment: by streaming stores are you referring to vmovntps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the inner loop is a mere streamed copy operation. Cache wouldn't matter in such a case. Rather try using simple memcpy() instead so the compiler can yield better execution code, hopefully.

```
//for(int j = 0;j < C/ 8; j++)
//{
//     __m256 a = _mm256_load_ps(&input[i * C + j * 8]);
//     _mm256_store_ps(&output[dest * C + j * 8] ,a);
//}

memcpy(&output[dest * C], &input[i * C], C * sizeof(float));
```

**Appendix**

If satisfiable results won't be obtained, in the last resort, take C++ and replace the outer loop with parllel_for(). Then it may be possible to make the cache(or otherwise pipeline?) work a little bit better.

```
parallel_for(0, A, [&](const int i) {

    for(int k = offsets[i]; k < offsets[i+1]; k++)
    {
       int dest = index1[k];
       memcpy(&output[dest * C], &input[i * C], C * sizeof(float));
     }
});
```

Comment: memcpy does the exact same thing under the hood. (or so I believe) at least I can't tell a difference between the runtime.

Comment: Oh, might be so. All possible optimizations are already utilized by the compiler. If prefetch instructions are already inserted appropriately by the compiler too, there might be not so much room for further optimization.

Comment: @bumpbump no memcpy can be faster with streaming stores on quite big chunks of data (and possibly unrolling).

Comment: @bumpbump: glibc memcpy has an unrolled loop that might be faster for medium-sized copies (like 2 to 16kiB) on data hot in L1d cache.  It does have function-call overhead, though.  A tight loop copying 32 bytes per iteration is reasonable, though, for non-huge data, especially on CPUs before Ice Lake (2 stores per clock for vectors < 64 bytes, but still only 1 loop iteration per clock.)  https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S.html